# android application error

Tags: java, android

my xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/mapView"

                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enable="true"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="0THdCiXY7jaJ9Br1ZQahFE4Lu1xTv1hAiVJBvxQ"
                 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.google.haha"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>  
        <activity android:name=".NewActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is main code:

```
package com.google.haha;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       mapV=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
       mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
       mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       double lat=21.00;
       double longi=79.00;
       GeoP=new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(longi*1E6));

       mControl=mapV.getController();
       mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
       mControl.setZoom(12);


    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine but I am getting error an on line:

```
mapV=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

id field is not recognised.

Comment: You know this problem comes up a lot. I know it has something to do with the import of the pre-compiled resources folder. I never did figure out why sometimes I needed to import it directly and why sometimes Eclipse handled the dependency.

Comment: The first thing you should is to clean your project, Project->Clean in main menu. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the error, but you may try cleaning the project. That should recompile your R.java file.

Comment: thanks everybody, that prob is resolved but nw i came up with other prob... m getting only gray tiles not maps... ny idea why dis hppning???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to clean and rebuild your project, because that problem comes up sometimes on Eclipse IDE , the id of your MapView is not recognised on your `R.java` file :

**Project ==> Clean ==> Choose your Project and Clic OK**

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    **android:enable="true"** MUST BE android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0THdCiXY7jaJ9Br1ZQahFE4Lu1xTv1hAiVJBvxQ"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```